# number toLocaleString with style percent is not correct

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Why is it that a toLocaleString of a float with the style percent is not correct. The decimal (dot) is ignored

```
1.23.toLocaleString('nl-NL', {style: 'percent'})

"123%"
```

With style decimal, it is correct

```
1.23.toLocaleString('nl-NL', {style: 'decimal'})

"1,23"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output `123%` for `1.23.toLocaleString('nl-NL', {style: 'percent'})`  is correct. `{style: 'percent'}` means that the number will be displayed as a percentage where percentages are a fractions of `100`, so the number `1` will be displayed as `100%`. In your case `1.23` will displayed as `123%` (100 + 23) as your output.